# Symfony Serializer xml encode append specified properties with CDATA

Tags: php, xml, symfony, serialization, symfony4

Is it possible to append string with CDATA using [Symfony Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) (not JMS).
By looking int to implementation it's only appends if string contains tag elements <>

```php
    private function needsCdataWrapping(string $val): bool
    {
        return 0 < preg_match('/[<>&]/', $val);
    }
```

Can you explicitly define specific attribute to be append with CDATA?

Comment: initially this doesn't make sense to do, so why would you? Do I understand correctly that you want to force CDATA encoding for *all* strings?

Comment: @Jakumi Not necessarily, I would like to explicitly define what attribute should be appended with CDATA, I corrected my question header ;)

Comment: Since you already found the correct serializer/encoder that is used, you probably also noticed that it's not possible with the existing serializer/encoder. You could theoretically write your own encoder, which is probably some work. If you wanted to make all strings CDATA, you could just copy the serializer and let the cited function always return true.

Comment: @Jakumi, Thanks, extended class and made some alterations. Was wondering is there any smarter way of doing it. ;)

Comment: smart is hard to measure. is there a simpler way? hardly. more complex? you could've built an unmaintainable monster instead. so I guess: well done ;o)